# Argument 1 of Node.appendChild does not implement interface Node

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to JavaScript, and i cannot figure out what are interface nodes? Below is my code with the error

```
Panel = function () {
   var popUpDiv = document.getElementById("firewall-content");
   var panelDiv = $("<div></div>").addClass("side_panel");
   popUpDiv.appendChild(panelDiv);
};
```

Comment: You cannot mix native DOM nodes and jQuery objects.  The two are not the same.  jQuery itself will often let you pass either a DOM node or a jQuery object, the native Javascript DOM functions such as `appendChild()` all require native DOM nodes and will not work with jQuery objects.  When using jQuery, you must know the difference between a jQuery object and a DOM node.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`appendChild` is a native DOM method and only accepts DOM nodes as a parameter. The element you're trying to append (`panelDiv`) is a jQuery object, not a DOM element. You can either append the DOM element:

```
Panel = function () {
   var popUpDiv = document.getElementById("firewall-content");
   var panelDiv = $("<div></div>").addClass("side_panel")[0];
   popUpDiv.appendChild(panelDiv);
};
```

Or use jQuery's built in functions all the way through your code (which you should anyway if you're using jQuery):

```
Panel = function () {
   var popUpDiv = $("#firewall-content");
   var panelDiv = $("<div></div>").addClass("side_panel");
   popUpDiv.append(panelDiv);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `javaScript`

```js
Panel = function () {
    var popUpDiv = document.getElementById("firewall-content");
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.style.width = "100px";
    div.style.height = "100px";
    div.innerHTML = "Hello";
    div.className = "side_panel";
    
    popUpDiv.appendChild(div);
};

Panel();
```

```css
.side_panel {
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="firewall-content"></div>
```

using `jQUery`

```js
Panel = function () {
    var panelDiv = $("<div> Hello World</div>").addClass("side_panel");
    
    $("#firewall-content").append(panelDiv);
};

Panel();
```

```css
.side_panel {
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="firewall-content"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem. Since JavaScript don't have the best error handling i got this error message.

I used following code:

```
var myArray = ['one','two', 'three']; 

for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {    
     alert(myArray[i]);
}
```

The problem was that myArray have three elements (with index id's 0,1,2) and I tried to access to element with index id 3. **Element myArray[3] don't exist** so I got message "TypeError: Argument 1 of Node.appendChild is not an object.". Maybe is this solution for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `panelDiv` is a jQuery object, not a dom element reference, and the Node.appendChild() expect a Node to be passed as its argument.

Since you are using jQuery, you can use the .append() method like

```
Panel = function () {
   var popUpDiv = $("#firewall-content");
   var panelDiv = $("<div></div>").addClass("side_panel");
   popUpDiv.append(panelDiv);
};
```

Or you can get the Node reference from the jQuery object like

```
Panel = function () {
   var popUpDiv = document.getElementById("firewall-content");
   var panelDiv = $("<div></div>").addClass("side_panel");
   popUpDiv.appendChild(panelDiv[0]);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myCtrl($scope) {
var count=0;
    $scope.wrapClonedDiv = function() {
     var iEl = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#paraID' ) );
     var wEl = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#wrapDIV' ) );

     iEl.append(wEl.clone().attr('id',"wrapDIV"+count));
count++;
    }

    $scope.wrapremoveDiv = function() {
     var iEl = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#wrapDIV'+count ) );
console.log(iEl);
iEl.remove()
count--;
    }
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<body>
<style>
div {
    border: 2px solid blue;
  }
p {
    background: yellow;
    margin: 4px;
  }
.wrapDIV {
    color: red;
    padding:5px;
    border:2px solid red;
}
</style>

<br/>
<button ng-click="wrapClonedDiv()">Wrap cloned DIV</button>
<button ng-click="wrapremoveDiv()">Wrap Remove DIV</button>
<br/>
<p id="wrapDIV">Hello</p>
<br/>
<div class="paraID" id="paraID">

</div>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This answer makes no attempt to explain why the code fixes the problem, or why it's better than the already accepted answer.